# Laravel : Attempt Auth Using API with running the AES_ENCRYPT

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, jwt, laravel-authentication

I'm having a problem trying to authenticate api with the `attemp()` function in laravel, because I need to run the `AES_ENCRYPT` function in **mysql** to be able to match my post data with the data in the database. this is the code i wrote in the controller i have

```php
        $user = User::select('*',DB::raw("AES_DECRYPT(id_user, 'AESKEY') as username, AES_DECRYPT(password, 'AESKEY') as passwd"))
            ->where('id_user', DB::raw("AES_ENCRYPT('" . $id_user . "', '...')"))
            ->where('password', DB::raw("AES_ENCRYPT('" . $password . "', '...')"))
            ->first();

        $encryptedIdUser = DB::table('user')->selectRaw("AES_ENCRYPT('" . $id_user . "', 'AESKEY') as id_user")->first();
        $encryptedPassword = DB::table('user')->selectRaw("AES_ENCRYPT('" . $password . "', 'AESKEY') as password")->first();

        if ($user) {
            if (!$token = Auth::guard('api')->attempt([
                "id_user" => $encryptedIdUser->id_user,
                "password" => $encryptedPassword->password,
            ])) {
                return response()->json([
                    'success' => false,
                    'message' => 'Authentication failed!',
                ], 401);
            }
        } else {
            return response()->json([
                'success' => false,
                'message' => "Username or password is incorrect or user doesn't exist",
            ], 401);
        }

        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'message' => 'Authentication success!',
            'token' => $token,
        ], 200);
```

from the code above I always get authentication failed, is there something wrong, can you help me. ?

the token is required to get the token from JWT

here is the code that I wrote in my `model` and `config/auth.php`

*auth.php*

```php
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'jwt',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ]
    ],

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],
        // 'users_api' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'user',
        // ],
    ],
```

*user.php* (model)

```php
namespace App\Models;

// use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;

class User extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    protected $table = 'user';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_user';

    public function getJWTIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    public function getJWTCustomClaims()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```